Removing all snaps from a basic (DNS) server
I'm running a basic DNS server on a space restricted LVM.   I notice there are about 250 megs of snaps - can I remove these from my VM?
The snaps are "core20, lxd and snapd".
I know that my DNS server is not using a snap - and I'm at a loss as to what these do or why they are there.

You've not told us what Ubuntu product & release you're using, so how are we to really know what is required or not?  Have you explored what packages you have installed that have depends rules on those packages? or why there were installed? They were installed for a reason, so ask an admin of that unstated system or look in logs of your unstated system for clues.

In a default Ubuntu Server setup (since 20.04, and even in some Desktop setups), the system default-installs / default-ships with lxd by default.  lxd is only available via Snaps, and have dependencies on snapd (to run snaps), and core20 (the core Ubuntu snap that LXD is built against to function with).
You can safely remove these three snaps in this way:
sudo snap remove lxd core20
sudo apt remove snapd

This will remove the two snaps and then snapd. This will remove the snaps from the system.
Note that if you intend to use LXD containers you will not be able to do this.
